# How to write view functions with different filter options in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a Django view function where it returns items from a model with filters to give the data I want. To change filters or invent new filters I copy this code as a new view or modify this code, so my filters are hardcoded:

```py
def Criticals(request):
    items = ScanData.objects.filter(Q(Project_Assigned__icontains="Hooli") & (Q(Risk__icontains="Critical")))
    numberIPs = items.count()
    Criticals = ScanData.objects.filter(Q(Risk="Critical") & (Q(Project_Assigned__icontains="Hooli")))
    Highs = ScanData.objects.filter(Q(Risk="High") & (Q(Project_Assigned__icontains="Hooli")))
    Mediums = ScanData.objects.filter(Q(Risk="Medium") & (Q(Project_Assigned__icontains="Hooli")))
    Lows = ScanData.objects.filter(Q(Risk="Low") & (Q(Project_Assigned__icontains="Hooli")))
    numberCriticals = Criticals.count()
    numberHighs = Highs.count()
    numberMediums = Mediums.count()
    numberLows = Lows.count()
    context = {
        'items': items,
        'header': 'The Hooli Project',
        'numberIPs': numberIPs,
        'numberCriticals': numberCriticals,
        'numberHighs': numberHighs,
        'numberMediums': numberMediums,
        'numberLows': numberLows,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Most of the time making new filters only means changing one word in the function to get the filtered data I need. Is this best practice or should I be using some other programming construct?

For example in given code there are three `Risk` filters so do I have to create 3 functions/views and 3 urls - one per risk (high, medium, low) and so on?

Answer (score 0):

You may want your url to look like this

```
http://localhost:8000/path/?risk=low
```

And filter base on the risk value

```
risk = ScanData.objects.filter(Q(Risk=request.GET.get('risk')) & (Q(Project_Assigned__icontains="Hooli")))
```

If you changed the url `risk=medium` it should filter it as risk medium

Is that what you want or I didn't understand you right ?

Comment: this sounds like its worth a shot, Ill let you know if it works, thanks!